# Codeigniter: result_array() to form_multiselect()

Tags: php, arrays, forms, codeigniter

I am pulling a queried result_array() and placing that array as the fields to select from in a form_multiselect(). What I can't seem to figure out is why the multi-select shows the array indexes followed by each queried result. Is this a problem with my array or are there form_multiselect options I am missing for the array indexes to not be shown?

And my code below:

```
public function get_tags() {
    $this->db->select('tag_name');
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->from('offers_tags');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $tags = $query->result_array();

    return $tags;  
}
```

My controller:

```
$this->data['tags']=$this->offer_model->get_tags();
```

My view:

```
<div class="control-group">
            <?= form_label('Tags: ', 'tag_targets', $label_attr);?>

            <div class="controls">
                <?= form_multiselect('tag_targets[]',$tags,'','id="geo-select"');?>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You have the order of the parameters wrong.

> The first parameter will contain the name of the field, the second
>   parameter will contain an associative array of options, and the third
>   parameter will contain the value or values you wish to be selected
>   http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

You could also var_dump the array to check the values if you're not sure

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you are specifying the options correctly.http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

you should be specifying the options like this:

```
$tags = array(
    'tag1Value'  => 'tag1Name',
    'tag2Value'  => 'tag2Name',
    'tag3Value'  => 'tag3Name',
    'tag4Value'  => 'tag4Name'
);
```

However what you are returning from your `get_tags` function is:

```
array(
    0 => array('tag_name'=> 'Tag1'),
    1 => array('tag_name'=> 'Tag2'),
    2 => array('tag_name'=> 'Tag3')
)
```

Each result is a separate array contained with a wrapping array.

You can get the results into the format needed for `form_multiselect` by looping through the items and creating a new array. In your `get_tags` function you can do the following.

```
$tags = array();
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   $tags[$row['tag_name']] = $row['tag_name'];
}
return $tags;
```